# How to keep component running in background in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web

I have a clock(interval) component where the time starts when a user visits the webpage but when the user move to other page and comes back to the clock page then the timer starts from beginning again.

How can I keep the Clock component running in background so no matter which webpage the user visits, the timer should keep going?

Thank you in advance

**CLOCK COMPONENT**

```
function Clock(props) {

    const [time, setTime] = useState(0);

    const run = true;

    useEffect(()=>{
        if (run=== true && time < 1440){
            var timerID = setInterval(() => tick(time),1000);

            return function cleanup(){
                clearInterval(timerID);
            };
        }
    },[run, time]);

    function tick(time){
        setTime(time + 10);
        console.log(time);
    }

    return (
        <div className="clock-space">
            <div className="clock">{time}</div>            
        </div>
    );
}
```

**App Component (that calls clock comp)**

```
return (
            <div className="box">
                <Header />
                <PageMenu name={this.state.page} data={this.changePageNameToDefault.bind(this)}/>
                <Clock />
                {renderComp}
            </div>
```

Comment: Or you can leave the time running out of the component (using Redux maybe?) and just bring it back as a prop when needed. In any case, making the component rerender all the time with the clock when it's not being seen sounds like a bad idea.

Comment: useRef holds up value for reference to other component, how will I reuse it if I return to the same Clock component. I am setting up the running time in react state in the same component. @AjeetShah

Comment: I have redited my question for better clarification. Please tell me how will I implement the functionalities in it.

Comment: consider 1440(24 hours) and 10 as minutes.. every second time+=10 (it actually has later usage to work with SVGs so for quick experiment I used 10 minutes increment)..

Comment: Your clock component is working fine. I can suggest minor changes. But you component is working. What's the issue?

Comment: `How can I keep the Clock component running in background so no matter which webpage the user visits, the timer should keep going?` Just use the `Clock` in a root level i.e. `App` component.

Comment: Wrap your component in Clock component

Comment: Hi @AjeetShah, sorry for the late response. Yes my component works fine, my concern was that it reloads the state `time` everytime I come back to Clock component.. to be more precise, my application is small where I am just replacing the components on single page.. and yes putting the timer function in App can fix this but my requirement will be ruined because it can affect the future usage and codes

Comment: @punit-doc I am unable to understand it now. If you want, you can share a github repo or sandbox. Or, if you have already fixed it, then it is Great!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no *running in the background*. I guess the issue here is that you somehow initiate a rerender of the component. And it depends on what kind of routing you use inside your application and if it should remember the time on a revisit/reload of the page.

If you use some kind of router (`react-router`, ...), you might just refactor your code so the Clock-Component is outside the render-procedure of the router. Otherwise you might want to use a `context` (`useContext`, `createContext`), which stores your timer. Something along the following lines:

```
// TimerContext.tsx
const TimerContext = React.createContext();

const TimeProvider = (props) => {
    const [time, setTime] = useState(0);
    const run = true;

    useEffect(()=>{
        if (run=== true && time < 1440){
            var timerID = setInterval(() => tick(time),1000);

            return function cleanup(){
                clearInterval(timerID);
            };
        }
    },[run, time]);

    function tick(time){
        setTime(time + 10);
        console.log(time);
    }


    const value = {
        run,
        time
    }
    return <TimerContext.Provider value={value} {...props} />
}

const useTimer = () => useContext(TimerContext)
```

```
// ClockComponent.tsx
const Clock = (props) => {
    const {time} = useTimer();

    return (
        <div className="clock-space">
            <div className="clock">{time}</div>            
        </div>
    );
}
```

Don't forget to render the TimeProvider somewhere on the top of your render hierarchy.

In case you don't have a routing framework or have issues with reloading, you have to work with localStorage (or some other kind of client storage). There really is no other way (except communication with a server) to keep up the timer navigating your page.

You might also combine both approaches.